# Jquery basic authentication error

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication, cordova

I am a newbie to Jquery. 
I am trying to send a request with basic authentication using jquery. This is what i do.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: domain,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(){
            alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
          },
          error:function(){
            alert('here');
          },
          beforeSend: function(xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password));
          }
});
```

But my problem is I dont get any feedack. Looks like both the success or the error method is called.

On further debugging i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: encodeBase64 is not defined
```

What am i missing? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in the console if there are any errors or with firebug what the response to your post is ?

Comment: updated my question with console output

Comment: then you have your error the function encodebase64 is undefined

Comment: android/iOS ?
or do u see this error while testing on browser?

Comment: This is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is saying that there is no method called encodeBase64 defined.

Many browsers have a built-in conversion from ascii to base64 called btoa:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));
```

If you are supporting older browsers, make sure that there is a base64 polyfill, such as the one at http://ww.w.icodesnip.com/search/javascript%20dark%20codes/45

Comment: thanks that helped. But when I deliberately change to a wrong username/password I find the error method is never called.

Comment: Does your server respond with a 401 status code when the username/password are wrong?

Comment: Yes it returns
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Unauthorized: Basic Authentication Required"
    }
}

Comment: Unless the HTTP status code is a 401, jQuery will be running the success handler instead of the error handler (it sees the XHR as having been successful if there is a 200 HTTP status code). You may find it easier to move your logic to the "complete" handler instead and check the message body of the response to see if there is an error or not.